# Can GPU be used for a general programming?

Tags: performance, gpu

It seems like for special tasks GPU can be 10x or more powerful than the CPU.

Can we make this power more accessible and utilise it for common programming?

Like having cheap server easily handling millions of connections? Or on-the-fly database analytics? Map/reduce/Hadoop/Storm - like stuff with 10x throughput? Etc?

Is there any movement in such direction? Any new programming languages or programming paradigms that will utilise it?

Comment: https://wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA is a good start

Comment: CUDA seems to be too low level

Comment: I very much recommend reading this: [Why are we still using CPUs instead of GPUs?](http://superuser.com/questions/308771/why-are-we-still-using-cpus-instead-of-gpus) Yes, GPUs are being used for general-purpose computations, but only for certain problems that work well in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

`CUDA` or `OpenCL` are good implementations of GPU programming.

GPU programming uses Shaders to process input buffers and almost instantly generate result buffers. Shaders are small algorithms units, mostly working with `float` values, which contains their own data context (input buffers and constants) to produce results. Each Shader is isolated from the other Shaders during a task, but you can chain them if required.

GPU programming won't be good at handling HTTP requests since this is mostly a complex sequential process, but it will be amazing to process, for example, a photo or a neural network.

As soon as you can chunk your data into tiny parallel units, then yes it can help. The CPU will remain better for complex sequential tasks.

*Colonel Thirty Two* links to a long and interesting answer about this if you want more informations : https://superuser.com/questions/308771/why-are-we-still-using-cpus-instead-of-gpus